# Symfony, Doctrine, mapping row

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, lazy-loading

I had problem with select and about 200ms on execute, use symfony2 and doctrine to generate Entity and connect to database.

My table had very `ManyToMany` connect with other tables.

when I try to make an inquiry, it takes 200ms through it without the many to many query rate is approximately 50 ms whether it is possible to set the doctrine that not mapped these fields at once? or somehow speed up the inquiry, it is plain `select * from table where ..... limit of 1`

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine [supports lazy loading](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/05/29/doctrine-lazy-loading.html).

You [can also set the `ManyToMany` association in your entity definitions to lazy load](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany).

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", fetch="LAZY")
```

Fetch supports one of the following: `LAZY`, `EXTRA_LAZY` or `EAGER`

Comment: nothnig change, when i clear cache i had near 90ms, on this select, after first run up to 200+ms